# Trying to move ng-repeat from img element to parent div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I currently have an ng-repeat on an img element that looks something like this:

```
<div class="mainContent" Overflow:scroll style="">
  <img class="imgClass" ng-src="{{movie.imgPath}}" ng-click="openInfo(movie)" data-ng-repeat="movie in filteredResults = (moviesArray | orderBy : 'title' | filter:{a bunch of filters}"/> 
</div>
```

I'm trying to move the ng-repeat into a parent div so that I can add a ribbon to some of the movies if an element in their individual object is true. Here is what I'm trying:

```
<div class="mainContent" Overflow:scroll style="" data-ng-repeat="movie in filteredResults = (moviesArray | orderBy : 'title' | filter:{a bunch of filters}">
  <img class="imgClass" ng-src="{{movie.imgPath}}"/>
</div>
```

When I do this, nothing shows up anymore.  Any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you just wrap the image tag in a div and move the ng-repeat to there instead of to the parent 'mainClass' which appears to be the container node and might have conflicting styles etc? more something more like the below (note I haven't had time to test)

```
<div class="mainContent" Overflow:scroll style="">
  <div ng-src="{{movie.imgPath}}" ng-click="openInfo(movie)" data-ng-repeat="movie in filteredResults = (moviesArray | orderBy : 'title' | filter:{a bunch of filters}">
    <img class="imgClass">
  </div>
</div>
```